# Format Oracle Date to work with MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, oracle10g, ms-access-2007

I've found a few questions on this but none seem to fit my problem case quite right.

**Overview**: Data is in Oracle 10g database, requirement including using MS Access as a front end.

**Problem**: The tables include date fields which are incompatible with MS Access. I *NEED* to run queries based on date and time in MS Access

**Details**:

1. I'm not allowed to redesign the tables
2. Decided to create new tables on the server and run inserts from the old tables to the new

   - Probably sounds weird but given the constraints I'm allowed to do what I want if I duplicate the data
3. With the new tables I want to take the date/time/timezone field from the old and insert it into a new table with the date/time but strip the timezone, put it in a field by itself

The big requirement is to have the data be usable. If I do a TO_CHAR it becomes a string and I can't setup queries based on date and time with that as it's a static text field at that point.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks !!!

Comment: *The tables include date fields which are incompatible with MS Access.* Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: Sure it's simple, when you add the time zone to the date field in an Oracle database Access can no longer see the fields properly when linked to the table via ODBC. Instead of showing a date it simply says OLE Object

Comment: Weird. I assume you've tried re-linking and also deleting the link and then re-adding them?

Comment: oh yea, I've relinked a few times. There's six tables with date fields using the time zones and all of them come up with OLE Object as Access doesn't like time zones in the same field as date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this. Looking here:

[Oracle Date Functions](http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html)

They give some samples wrapping a to_char with to_date. I formatted this in a way to convert it to text stripping the time zone then wrapped it with the to_date to convert it back to a date and time field that's compatible with MS Access. Here's the code:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(table.date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM table.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible the best way I have found to deal with these issues is to link to the table via a view. You can then present the data how you wish under the hood without having to alter the table structures.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply but can that new view be sorted by a date range? So if I use a view to alter the structure changing the date to a text field what then? Or can I alter the view and have a date still be a date?